# Diff in Diff Callaway and Sant’anna small number of treated units larger number of controls?

Tags: sample-size, difference-in-difference

I am pretty new to r and statistics. I am trying to use the DiD package for difference in differences with multiple time periods. I have 60 control units and 17 treated units. Is this sample size large enough? Does this imbalance between treatment and control size alter the accuracy of the ATT? If so are there any solutions in r? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you have just $77$ observations?

Comment: @Dave Yes just 77.

Comment: Or no I mean I have data for 10 years before the treatment and 10 years after for each of the the 77 units. The data points are at the county year level.